# how to correctly deal with calling GAS from js client through JSONP when getting "grant access" html?

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, jsonp

hello all i havent managed to find this elsewhere here nor in the old GAS product forum so here goes:

i am writing a simple client javascript which queries various APIs. when it comes to querying a certain GAS script i have set up to access gmail, i understand i am supposed to [serve its data through JSONP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/content_service#serving_jsonp_in_web_pages). the client script dynamically injects a `SCRIPT` tag and should normally handle this "response" as script. except whenever the response contains [html, requesting the user to grant permissions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_google_accounts#grantingAccess). in this case this `HTML` goes into the `SCRIPT` raising syntax error with MIME type mismatch.

researching this problem i was led to believe the solution lies somewhere around redirecting the user to this page always before every call. so my question is, where can i find best practice regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a full solution for detecting and granting authorizations to scripts used in JSONP requests. I've seen workarounds where an application first prompts the users to visit the web app's URL, so that they can grant authorization, before allowing them to use the JSONP portion of the application.